# Stackexchange never notifies me about anything

Tags: support, notifications

It’s as the title of this question says : even though I log in with yahoo, I am never notified about anything at all (answers or comments to my questions, even when I put them into my “favorites”). Perhaps this problem is related to my being unable to log to any chat room (I asked about that [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/unable-to-log-in-to-a-chat-room) too and nobody could find a solution).

I come from MathOverflow and I remember that in comparison the MathOverflow system worked fine for me, it always notified me about  the things I wanted to know and nothing else.

I never worried much about this, but the most tiresome aspect of my problem is missing a comment on one of my answers.

Perhaps I should create a new fresh stackoverflow account and leave my current, dysfunctional account.

Comment: If you do happen to make a new fresh account and that resolves the problem, I believe the moderators can merge your current account under the new one. Hence you wouldn't lose your link to your current questions, answers, and favorites.

Comment: I have a similar issue--I am notified of new answers to my questions and to replies on comments, but not when I get a new badge.  I thought I read somewhere this was supposed to happen...

Comment: Just to clarify: You get notifications neither in your inbox, neither on you response tab. ([Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114631/eeeeek-wheres-my-comment-notification) is a meta.SO questions, where the problem was that a user received a notification on response tab, but not in his inbox.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak : as several other users, I don’t want notification in my inbox, the response tab is fine. Encouraged by yunone’s comment above, I created a new fresh stackoverflow account. And mysteriously, when I returned to the old account, I found that notification was now working! I was indeed notified about your comment in my response tab.